# Set up Oracle 12c R1 to connect to web service

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql

I have set up ACL using DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN package. Here it's

[image]

But when I am trying to connect to the above web service using GET, I am getting error

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 368
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1118
ORA-06512: at "APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 550
ORA-06512: at "APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 197
ORA-06512: at line 7
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
```

I would also like to mention host oracle-base.com is working perfectly. below code works fine.

```
declare
l_response CLOB;
l_url varchar2(4000) := 'http://oracle-base.com/webservices/add-numbers.php'; --web service URL
l_result NUMBER;
begin
---get XML from 
l_response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => l_url,
                                                 p_http_method => 'GET',
                                                 p_parm_name  => apex_util.string_to_table('p_int_1:p_int_2'),
                                                 p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table('12:12')
                                                );


dbms_output.put_line(l_response);
--parse the response
l_result :=apex_web_service.parse_xml(p_xml => XMLTYPE(l_response), --convert CLOB to XML
                           p_xpath => '//number/text()'
                        );
dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
end;
```

but when I am tryig to do the same for reqres.in it's getting failed. How I added reqres.in

```
DECLARE
  l_principal VARCHAR2(20) := 'APEX_040200';
  --l_principal VARCHAR2(20) := 'APEX_050000';
  --l_principal VARCHAR2(20) := 'APEX_050100';
  --l_principal VARCHAR2(20) := 'APEX_180200';
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.append_host_ace (
    host       => 'reqres.in', 
    lower_port => 80,
    upper_port => 80,
    ace        => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('http'),
                              principal_name => l_principal,
                              principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db)); 
END;
/
```

The command I am trying to execute :

```
declare
l_response CLOB;
l_url varchar2(4000) := 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'; --web service URL
l_result NUMBER;
begin
---get XML from 
l_response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => l_url,
                                                 p_http_method => 'GET'
--                                                 p_parm_name  => apex_util.string_to_table('p_int_1:p_int_2'),
--                                                 p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table('12:12')
                                                );


dbms_output.put_line(l_response);
----parse the response
--l_result :=apex_web_service.para(p_xml => XMLTYPE(l_response), --convert CLOB to XML
--                           p_xpath => '//number/text()'
--                        );
dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
--APEX_JSON.parse(l_result); -- APEX_JSON is not available

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an HTTPS request, the first thing you need to do is to specify the correct port. HTTPS uses 443 whereas HTTP uses 80:

```
     DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.append_host_ace (
       host       => 'reqres.in', 
       lower_port => 443,
       upper_port => 443,
       ace        => xs$ace_type(....
```

This should get rid of the `ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)` error.  However, after doing this, you may get a `ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure` error instead.

If this happens, you'll need to create an Oracle Wallet to store the root certificate used by https://reqres.in/ (i.e. the Sectigo one), ensure that the database has permission to read this wallet, and add the wallet details to the call to [`apex_web_service.make_web_request`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_web_service.htm#AEAPI1955):

```
l_response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
  p_url => l_url,
  p_http_method => 'GET',
--p_parm_name  => apex_util.string_to_table('p_int_1:p_int_2'),
--p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table('12:12')
  p_wallet_path => 'path/to/your/wallet',
  p_wallet_pwd => 'YourWalletPasswordHere'
);
```

Comment: Thanks Luke! I will try this out and update. I am using Windows as OS. I have seen ab article where it describes to process to create a wallet. I will try that out and update here. Thanks

Comment: So I have created a wallet and added the path to the web service call. I have also added the certificate to the wallet. But now I a getting a different error.

RA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "APEX_180200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1017
ORA-28759: failure to open file
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1148
ORA-06512: at "APEX_180200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 917
ORA-06512: at "APEX_180200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1523
ORA-06512: at "APEX_180200.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 369

CONTD..

Comment: l_response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => l_url,
                                                 p_http_method => 'GET',
                                                 p_wallet_path => 'file:C:\app\db_home\bin\ow\wallets',
                                                 p_wallet_pwd => 'walletpassWord'
                                                );

Comment: During installation, I had chosen the option to create a new Windows user for oracle services. is it the reason? it may not have access to "C" drive?

Comment: I just checked the wallet folder access for the oracleuser - it has access and I have also added it to admin group.

Comment: @redsoxlost: I had a similar issue.  In the end I gave Read access on the wallet files (the `cwallet.sso` and `ewallet.p12` files in the wallet directory) to the Users group and that seemed to work.

Comment: yes that's what I did at last. I gave read access to the wallet files ewallet.p12 & ewallet.p12.lck to the oracle users. It worked!