# apex_web_service.make_rest_request required ACL privileges

Tags: oracle, web-services, oracle-apex, acl, privileges

I'm following [this tutorial](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6121/index-en.html) to access a secure web service from PL/SQL. The following code works (as user SYSTEM):

```
select utl_http.request(
    'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson',
    wallet_path => 'file:c:\oracle\wallet\https_wallet',
    wallet_password => '******'
) from dual;
```

However, instead of `utl_http.request`, I need to use the `apex_web_service.make_rest_request` API for its additional features:

```
select apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
    p_url => 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson', 
    p_http_method => 'GET',
    p_wallet_path => 'file:c:\oracle\wallet\https_wallet') from dual;
```

This returns:

```
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
```

My configured ACLs:

```
select privilege, host, lower_port, upper_port
from dba_network_acl_privileges p
join dba_network_acls a on a.aclid = p.aclid
where principal = 'SYSTEM';

PRIVILEGE                HOST  LOWER_PORT UPPER_PORT
------------------------ ----- ---------- ----------
resolve                  *                          
connect                  *                          
use-client-certificates  *                          
use-passwords            *                          
http                     *
```

What additional ACL or privilege does `apex_web_service.make_rest_request` need over and above `utl_http.request`?

Using Oracle XE 18c / Windows 10

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577403/set-up-oracle-12c-r1-to-connect-to-web-service) about `ORA-24247`

Comment: Also, in general you should not use the SYSTEM account or any other Oracle default account to execute application code. It is an over-privileged account and should be locked at all times. Use a custom account that has only the minimum number of privileges required for the application to work.

Comment: @Kumar The problem with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577403/set-up-oracle-12c-r1-to-connect-to-web-service) was with port restrictions. As shown above I have no port restrictions. So, I appreciate your attempt to help, but I don't know why you link the two.

Comment: @pmdba Yes, in general I should also not grant all privileges for all hosts. But these are debugging strategies while dealing with mysterious permission error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an ACL for the APEX schema with connect privilege as well as an ACL for the APEX schema to access your wallet as you make use of HTTPS

Comment: There is no schema called "APEX" on my instance. Can you clarify, please?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you, execute in sysdba:

```
declare 
vAcl varchar2(300);
BEGIN
SELECT acl into vAcl  FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
  WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;
--APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.VALIDATE_EMAIL_CONFIG;
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(vAcl,
  'APEX_220100', TRUE, 'connect');
    
END;
```